# mysql fetch and update not working on too much request

Tags: php

i am trying to get data from database and update ...  like i have balance column and i getted 20 and i want to add 10 and update...

if 1 request in 2-3 secound than this working.. But If I Have 10-20 request in 1 secound than this not working ....

**Example : **

**Normal request :** updated balance: 10
updated balance: 20
updated balance: 30
updated balance: 40
updated balance: 50

updated balance: 60

this working ...

**High request :** updated balance: 10
updated balance: 20
updated balance: 30
updated balance: 30
updated balance: 30
updated balance: 40

updated balance: 40
updated balance: 50
updated balance: 50
updated balance: 50
updated balance: 60

I Am tring to solve i have this code

```
<form method='POST'>
    
    <button type='submit' name='submit' >SUBMIT</button>
    
</form>

<?php

// Connecting to the Database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; 
$database = "bug_check";

// Create a connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Die if connection was not successful
if (!$conn){
    die("Sorry we failed to connect: ". mysqli_connect_error());
    return;
}
else{
    $conne = true;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$junburyleadqury=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `bug_test` where id='1'");
$record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($junburyleadqury) ;

$balance=$record['balance'];
$total_earn=$record['total_earn'];

$total_earnNEW=10+$total_earn;
$balanceNEW=10+$balance;

file_put_contents('bug-test.txt', file_get_contents('bug-test.txt')."total_earn : $total_earnNEW balance: $balanceNEW
");

sleep(1); // this is for load..

$update=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `bug_test` SET `balance` = '$balanceNEW' WHERE `bug_test`.`id` = 1;");
$update2=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `bug_test` SET `total_earn` = '$total_earnNEW' WHERE `bug_test`.`id` = 1;");


}


?>
```

For Check : click submit button click 1-5 time slowly - slowly  ..  go and check bug-test.txt upadte working fine..

but if you click submit button multiple time - than update not working you can check in bug-test.txt    this file...

i have this sql..

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Generation Time: Aug 02, 2023 at 04:09 AM
-- Server version: 10.6.12-MariaDB-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 7.2.34

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `bug_check`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `bug_test`
--

CREATE TABLE `bug_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_earn` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `balance` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bug_test`
--

INSERT INTO `bug_test` (`id`, `total_earn`, `balance`) VALUES
(1, '310', '310');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `bug_test`
--
ALTER TABLE `bug_test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `bug_test`
--
ALTER TABLE `bug_test`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer but you need to find a way to send less requests per second. Do a longer singular query, 10+ queries per second is way too many and will crash most databases if they arent load managed.